# jQuery loses select value

Tags: jquery, html-select

I am preparing linked dropdown in which selecting first dropdown change value of second one. following is my code. It changes the value.

```
$('#subSelect option[data-option="option0"]').show();
$('#mainSelect').live('change', function () {

    $('#subSelect option').hide();
    $('#subSelect option[data-option="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
    var $myva = $('#mainSelect').attr('title');
    alert($myva);
    $('#subSelect option:visible:first').attr('selected', true);
});
$('#mainSelect').trigger('change');
```

I lose the actual values of the dropdown and it gives option0, option1 - option13. please guide.

Comment: Welcome to SO. post your html and jquery code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: please share the html of the select also

Comment: im sorry, this just looks very backwards to me, why `hide` and `show`? whats the point of `$myva`? and btw `live` is outdated use `on` - http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/salmanrazak/QDxTk/

Comment: please use this link and guide me
http://jsfiddle.net/salmanrazak/QDxTk/

Comment: just like select country to get city. and alert city name

Comment: @Arun P Johny any help?

Comment: @SalmanRazak see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $sub = $('#subSelect');
var subOpts = $sub.html();

$('#subSelect option:not([data-option="option0"])').remove();
$('#mainSelect').on('change', function () {
    var select = $(this).val();

    $sub.empty();
    var opts = $(subOpts).filter('[data-option="' + select + '"], [data-option="option0"]').appendTo($sub)

    $sub.val(opts.first().val())
}).trigger('change');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6yrwC/)